# Apple SSD TSC 128 GB on Windows desktop

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, hard-drive, ssd

My MacBook Pro 2011 is having problems. When I turn it on, I hear the chime but the screen is black. I am planning to send it off to Apple since I have AppleCare. But before I do that, I need to backup my hard drive. I have taken the hard drive out and plugged it into my desktop, but I don't see it. I see it in device manager - > Apple TSC 128 GB, but how can I browse through the contents and save the stuff? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your MBP uses the HFS+ files system which Windows cannot natively read. You will need something like [HFS+ for windows](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/) or [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/) to get it to work. [Catacobae](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsx.html) looks to be free and people like it on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/catacombae/).

Comment: +1 for MacDrive. Been using it for years with not one problem. Just terrific.